# Failed to Import-Module MSOnline in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, powershell

We have created a mini web program for running PowerShell in asp.net. the PowerShell command is running fine. but when we try to import the MSOnline module, it will be shown the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline\Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.

```
Dim Ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()

Dim tempScript As String = "Import-Module MSOnline " + Environment.NewLine
tempScript = tempScript + "$username = 'xxx@xxx.com' " + Environment.NewLine
tempScript = tempScript + "$password = 'abcd1234' " + Environment.NewLine
tempScript = tempScript + "$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force " + Environment.NewLine
tempScript = tempScript + "$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $secureStringPwd " + Environment.NewLine
tempScript = tempScript + "Connect-MsolService -Credential $creds " + Environment.NewLine
tempScript = tempScript + "Get-MsolDomain" + Environment.NewLine

Ps.Commands.AddScript(tempScript)

' Execute the script
Dim results = Ps.Invoke()
```

PS C:> $PSVersionTable | Out-String

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Update : 3-Aug-2017

Try to use process.start to call a CMD, and then the cmd call a powershell, but it failed also. same error message.

```
Private Function RunBatch() As String
Dim proc As New Process
Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder

proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\temp\enableMFA.bat"
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
proc.Start()
proc.WaitForExit()

Dim output() As String = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd.Split(CChar(vbLf))
For Each ln As String In output
    strBuilder.Append(ln & vbNewLine + vbLf)
Next

Return strBuilder.ToString

End Function
```

Error Message:

> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Preview\Preview\bin\Debug>powershell -File
>   "C:\temp\enableMFA.ps1"
>
> Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline\Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.dll'
>   or
>
> one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.
>
> At C:\temp\enableMFA.ps1:1 char:1
>
> - Import-Module MSOnline
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], BadImageFormatException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: Most probably a bitness problem? https://ziaahmedshaikh.wordpress.com/2015/09/11/configure-windows-powershell-to-connect-with-o356/

Comment: i try to call the PowerShell with process.start in VB.NET, also failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue by change the CPU to x64, this is the steps

> - Right click the project >> properties >> complie >> Target CPU to x64
> - Go to TOOLS >> Options >> Projects and Solutions >> Web Projects >>    use 64bit IIS Express

** Remember close the VS2013 and open the project again **

> ** Thx for the hints from David Brabant**